# Activity indicator using WKWebView doesn't disappear

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

Please i need assistance using the WKWebView. I cannot make activity indicator disappear. I have tried using the self.webView.navigationDelegate = self but u get this error "Insert ' as! WKNavigationDelegate'"

Please any suggestion to fix this would be greatly appreciated

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

     self.webView.navigationDelegate = self


    let url = URL(string:"https://example.com/")
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    self.webView.load(urlRequest)

}

@IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!



func didStartProvisionalNavigation (_ : WKWebView){
    activity.startAnimating()
}


func didFinishNavigation (_ : WKWebView){
    activity.stopAnimating()
}




override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if CheckInternet.Connection(){


    }

    else{

        self.Alert(Message: "Your Device is not connected to the internet")
    }

}

func Alert (Message: String){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: Message, 
 preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: 
  UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

//

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
```

//

also implement correct signature

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!){}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!){}
```